# span with position:absolute won't create scrollbar on container overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want absolute-positioned SPANs inside a container show scrollbars on the container when its position overflows the container.

However, even with overflow:auto on the container, the SPAN flies outside the container div, as if it does not belong to the container.

I will append many SPANs, so other values of position (like relative) will mess the independent positioning desired for each SPAN, albeit making the scrollbars.

Here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/v8x2bot4/1/

CSS:

```
.container {
  background-color: #AFF;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.fly {
  border: solid black 1px;
  background-color: #0F0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <span class="fly" style="left:450px; top:100px">blablablablabla</span>
  <span class="fly" style="left:300px; top:200px">blablabla2</span>
</div>
```

How can I hide the overflowing part of the SPAN and make a scrollbar appear as needed?

Hope HTML+CSS can do it without javascript. But solutions with javascript that work regardless of the number of SPANs should be very easy to maintain and suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to .container

https://jsfiddle.net/xfmrtx3s/

Comment: I would never imagine that. Is there an explanation for this trick according to the HTML specification?